# Is java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService should be closed as java.sql.Connection?

Tags: java, executorservice

I doubt whether `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` should be shutdown after all tasks had been completed or canceled?

I have a method like this:

```
public void testProxies() {

    // 5 thread
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    try {
        while(condition){
            exec.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //some task
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        exec.shutdown();// should be shutdown here?
    }
}
```

Is that a currect way of using `ExecutorService`?

How can I reuse the `ExecutorService`?

`ExecutorService` should be shutdown or let it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you shut it down, you can't reuse it.
- If you don't shut it down, your program won't be able to exit because there will be live non daemon threads.

So you need to call `shutdown` at some stage to let your program exit, but only when you know that you don't need to submit additional tasks to your executor.

What I generally do:

- I make the ExecutorService a field of my class
- I provide a `stop` or `shutdown` method which the user of my class needs to call which calls the shutdown method of the executor. Note that the executor won't actually shutdown until all the submitted tasks have completed (or have been successfully cancelled).

An alternative is to add a shutdown hook which will shutdown your executor when the JVM exits.

Comment: I don't really agree with you. Even if there are tasks running in the executor, your program will still exit if System.exit() is called. Also the shutdown method should be called when the executor is not needed anymore, and it should not accept more tasks (this does not mean that if there are running tasks they will be terminated and your program will exit nicely).

Comment: @AlexCalugarescu That's not what I said. `System.exit()` will indeed terminate the program even if the executor is not shutdown, but if you shutdown the executor, the program can terminate without the need for a `System.exit()` call.

Comment: @AlexCalugarescu And I agree that shutdown does not cancel running tasks (shutdownNow does) - but I did not imply that either.

Comment: Well, the general way of handling this is making sure your tasks will complete eventually and make sure you provide a stop method for them (where possible). I would also say that calling shutdownNow() is not an viable option because it does not guarantee that the active running threads will be stopped. Check out the documentation : http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: @AlexCalugarescu ShutdownNow will interrupt the running tasks - if they don't respond to interruption nothing will happen. Not sure why you link to netty's executors...

Comment: Sorry about that... The correct link would be : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29

Comment: Yes, nothing will happen and your application will still fail to stop (nothing will happen if your threads will not lock themselves). So, stopping the execution of your tasks just by shutting down the Executor Service is a bad practice.

Comment: @AlexCalugarescu I agree with that too - but once again I never said that calling shutdown would cancel anything. I only said 2 things: once shutdown is called you can't submit new tasks and before calling shutdown your program can't exit, even if all tasks have completed (unless you call System.exit() as you pointed out).

Comment: Then I don't understand what you meant by : "I provide a stop or shutdown method which the user of my class needs to call which calls the shutdown method of the executor."

Comment: When the client is done using my class (typically because the program is going to exit), he can call `myClass.stop()` which will shutdown the executor that my class uses. Sorry for the confusion. I have added a note to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. ExecutorService should be shutdown, if you don;t want to execute any tasks any more.

Comment: You can't re-use if you shutdown, if you want to re-use, you can just submit tasks like you did in your code without shutdonw.